# Is there a behavioral equivalent to the AES256TextEncryptor Class of the Jasypt-Library in CryptoJS?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes, cryptojs, jasypt

As a newbie to Cryptography, I'm trying to reproduce the same default behavior of the AES256TextEncryptor Class of the jasypt-library with the CrpytoJS library. This is my Java method, that basically takes in two arguments - the message that I want to encrypt as well as my secret paraphrase:

```
private String encryptWithAes256(String messageToBeEncrypted, String encryptorSecret) {
    AES256TextEncryptor encryptor = new AES256TextEncryptor();
    encryptor.setPassword(encryptorSecret);
    return encryptor.encrypt(messageToBeEncrypted);
}
```

When encrypting the messageToBeEncrypted with this code, the resulting encrypted message is fine. What I found out is that the AES256TextEncryptor, which internally uses the StandardPBEStringEncryptor as a encryptor, seems to use the PBEWithHMACSHA512AndAES_256 algorithm as a default.

How can I reproduce the same encryption behavior with CrpytoJS? When I'm trying to encrypt the message with CryptoJS in the way it's documented [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#ciphers), the result is totally different from what I expect it to be.

Based on Topaco's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604269/is-there-a-behavioral-equivalent-to-the-aes256textencryptor-class-of-the-jasypt#comment117838807_66604269), I came up with the following JavaScript Code to mimic the Java code:

```js
function encryptWithAes256(messageToEncrypt, encryptorKey){
      // Generate random 16 bytes salt
      var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
    
      // Derive key
      var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(encryptorKey, salt, { keySize: 256/32, iterations: 1000 });
      console.log("derived key: " + key);
    
      // Generate random 16 bytes init vector (iv)
      var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
    
      var cipherText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(messageToEncrypt, key, {iv: iv});
      console.log("aes encrypted text: "+ salt.toString() + iv.toString() + cipherText.toString());
      }
```

The generated result still seems not be as expected though, as it's length is 88 characters, whereas the Java code generates a 64 character long encrypted message.

Comment: `encryptWithAes256()` uses PBKDF2 to derive a 32 bytes key from the passphrase `encryptorSecret` and a randomly generated 16 bytes salt. The iteration count is _1000_, the used digest _SHA512_. Then a random 16 bytes IV is generated. Key and IV are used to encrypt the plaintext `messageToBeEncrypted` with AES-256 in CBC mode and PKCS7 padding. Finally, salt, IV and ciphertext are binary concatenated in that order and the result Base64 encoded. CryptoJS provides all the functionality for this. Please adapt your code, and if you get stuck, post the code and describe the problem.

Comment: The result that `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("my password to encrypt", "my encryptor key").toString()` returns is much shorter in characters than what the java-code above returns. My inital expectation was, that they would behave the same. They obviously behave differently internally, or am I missing something here?

Comment: What needs to be implemented on the JavaScript side to mimic the functionality of the Java code is described in detail in the comment above. I don't see how this can be implemented by a one-liner. You need four steps: 1. key derivation with PBKDF2 in conjunction with a random salt, 2. generation of a random IV, 3. encryption of the plaintext with the derived key and IV and 4. concatenation of salt, IV and ciphertext.

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion & added a little JavaScript implementation to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code is close to the required result. The following still needs to be corrected:

- PBKDF2 applies SHA1 by default, which means SHA512 must be explicitly specified.
- The concatenation must be done on a binary level and not with the hex and Base64 encoded data.

If this is fixed, a possible implementation is:

```js
function encryptWithAes256(messageToEncrypt, encryptorKey){
    // Generate random 16 bytes salt
    var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
    
    // Derive key
    var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(
        encryptorKey, 
        salt, 
        { keySize: 256/32, iterations: 1000, hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA512 }     // Apply SHA512
    );                                                                         
    console.log("derived key:\n" + key);
    
    // Generate random 16 bytes init vector (iv)
    var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
    
    // Encrypt
    var cipherText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(messageToEncrypt, key, {iv: iv});
    
    // Concatenate
    var encryptedData = salt.clone().concat(iv).concat(cipherText.ciphertext);  // Concatenate on binary level
    var encryptedDataB64 = encryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);         // Base64 encode the result
    console.log("aes encrypted text:\n", encryptedDataB64.replace(/(.{56})/g,'$1\n')); 
}

encryptWithAes256('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'my passphrase');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Since because of the random salt and IV always different data is generated, a test of the implementation is not possible by comparing the data. Instead, it must be checked whether the data generated with the CryptoJS code is decryptable with the Jasypt counterpart for decryption:

```
private static String decryptWithAes256(String ciphertextToBeDecrypted, String encryptorSecret) {
    AES256TextEncryptor encryptor = new AES256TextEncryptor();
    encryptor.setPassword(encryptorSecret);
    return encryptor.decrypt(ciphertextToBeDecrypted); 
}
```

which is indeed the case with the above CryptoJS implementation.

Comment: This indeed seems to work just fine! Could you elaborate though, what the `salt.clone()` is doing?

Comment: Without `clone()`, the concatenated result would be written into `salt`, losing the original value, i.e. the salt. With `clone()` a copy of `salt` is created and the concatenated result is written into the copy. In this example, `clone()` could be omitted, since the salt is not needed afterwards. But in general it is more robust not to change the original data, i.e. `salt`, but to work on a copy, s. online [here](https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/WeirdImperfectSystemadministrator).

Comment: I see, sounds like a best practice :) Another question would be, what the purpose of `encryptedDataB64.replace(/(.{56})/g,'$1\n')` is and if it is necessary? In my case, it seems to work without applying this replace call on the base64 encoded data.

Comment: @Mh_tm92 - This is only for the [Runnable JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) demo in my answer. If the output is too long, some browsers do not generate an automatic line break and also do not generate a scrollbar, so that part of the data is not visible. To avoid this, the statement simply forces a line break after every 56 bytes. Thus, you can ignore/omit that.